# Allow any web page to connect to Chrome APP

Tags: google-chrome, port, google-chrome-app

Is there any way to allow any web page to connect to Google App using externally_connectable.

Some thing like:

```
 "externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["*"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to host a https server with a valid certificate inside the Chrome app, in order to pull this off.

Alternatively, I bet you could create an iframe on any page that would be able to communicate to the extension/app